# How to sym-link python3_dlib into cv environment in pi?

Tags: pi-2

If I import cv2 into the Python3_dlib environment it can easily be found. But when I try to import dlib from the cv environment, it is giving "No module found". It may be for sym-link. But, when I was installing opencv, I made the sym-link to cv.so. Now, how can I sym-link dilb into the cv environment?